# Regarding the separation line in the expression of sets

Tags: math-mode, macros, mathtools

I defined a command `\set[<size>]{<first>}{<second>}` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` from `mathtools` for typesetting (mathematical) sets, which accepts one optional argument and two mandatory arguments: when the second mandatory argument is empty, the result is `{ <first> }`; and when it is not empty, the result is `{ <first> | <second> }`.

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX \set [2] \lbrace \rbrace
  {
    \mskip1.5mu
    #1
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \mskip2.5mu \delimsize\vert \mskip2.5mu #2 }
    \mskip1.5mu
  }
```

My questions here are related to the separation line (in the above code it is `\delimsize\vert`):

1. How to make it a dashed or dotted line? (*The difficulty for me here is that I don't know how to make it adopting to the size given by the optional argument*)
2. How to make the line bolder? (*`\mathbf` does not work here*)

(I would like to try out these styles in my document, as sometimes a plain vertical line does not look very clear in this notation, for example when there is `\mid` in the content)

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
% \usepackage{newpxmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX \set [2] \lbrace \rbrace
  {
    \mskip1.5mu
    #1
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \mskip2.5mu \delimsize\vert \mskip2.5mu #2 }
    \mskip1.5mu
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
    \set{a}{\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\[
    \set[\bigg]{a}{\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want it to be dashed, dotted, and bolder? Would you like it to be pink, too? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Actually I just wish to know how can these styles be achieved (a plain vertical line sometimes is not very clear in this notation). It wouldn't be hard to draw them with Ti*k*Z, but making it automatically adopt to the `\delimsize` seems difficult.

Comment: Yes, I don’t think there’s a really clear classic TeX solution to just make a scaled delimiter dashed or dotted. If you are okay with using TikZ, you could try to use TeX to measure the height of `\delimsize|` (e.g. via the command `\settoheight`) and then use TikZ to draw a vertical line with that length. I don’t know how well it would work in practice, though.

Comment: Let's see... I think you obviously can extract it from delimsize somehow, but since it's only given as a macro that modifies the following delimiter it's not very-easy to extract the height from it (apart from measuring some delimiter)

Comment: This is why I tend to use the `\Set{A \given B}` syntax. Then we don't need to test the values. Your first case is then just `\Set{ A }` and it works by default. The code for `\Set` is an example in the `mathtools` manual.

Comment: There's a thing called "leader" in TeX for dashed/dotted things but I'm not that familiar with it...

Comment: Looks like the `\delimsize` is a macro defined to be either \MH@empty (empty), \big, \Big, \bigg, etc. but I don't think it's a good idea to rely on that implementation details. Measuring the height of a \delimsize| is better.

Comment: @daleif We are quite a few people who, following Knuth’s recommendation, like to have an extra space next to the braces in set constructions, equivalent to `\{\, ... \mid ... \,\}`. So I would always use different macros for set constructions and sets with comma-separated elements.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for this suggestion, I didn't know this before. Too bad that I have used my syntax for many hundreds of times in my document, making it a little difficult to switch to new syntax. But again, I'm still wondering how to get dashed or dotted line, or at lease make the separation line border to differ from e.g. division symbol in the content. (Trying with Ti*k*Z, shouldn't be that hard now that I realized that one can measure the length of `\delimsize|`)

Comment: @Jinwen given that delimiters are special beast I'd be surprised if one even could make a dashed delimiter without a special font. I used the `\Set{a}{b}` syntax for a while but over time it makes the the code harder to read.

Comment: @Gaussler Measuring the height of `\delimsize|` doesn't seem to be easy. To measure it, one has to (?) put it inside the box, but then information of the current math mode would be lost.

Comment: I feared as much, but wasn’t sure. This sounds like a job for Super-@egreg. `;-)`

Comment: @Jinwen I guess that when not using autoscaling, `\delimsize` expands to `\big`, `\Big`, and friends. So if you do `\let\temp=\delimsize` or use an expanded `\def`, I guess you could store the size for future use inside `\settoheight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof of concept. You may want to use Ti*k*Z for a better dashed or dotted line, but the idea is the same: measure the height plus depth of `\delimsize\vert`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set [2] \lbrace \rbrace
  {
    \mspace{1.5mu}
    #1
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { \mathrel{\dashedsep} #2 }
    \mspace{1.5mu}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\dashedsep}{%
  \sbox0{$\delimsize\vert$}%
  \vcenter to \dimexpr \ht0+\dp0 {\offinterlineskip
    \cleaders\vbox{\vskip0.5pt\hbox{\vrule width 0.4pt height 1pt}\vskip0.5pt}\vfill
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\set{x}{x^2<0}$

$\set[\Big]{x}{x^2<0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

No, thanks.

Comment: Hey, speaking of this, I would like a version where the line is replaced by a vertical sequence of flying pink unicorns. Could you update your answer with this? `;-)`

Comment: Also, perhaps you want `\m@th` in `$\delimsize\vert$`, just for consistency (even though we only need its height, not its width)?

Comment: Also`^2`, this throws an error when using `\set*`.