# Failed to use TikZ to draw lines matching \delimsize

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, macros, mathtools

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647725/194994) @egreg proposed a method to use dashed line in the notation of sets.

In a similar way, I would like to use Ti*k*Z to draw the separation line. The idea is also to measure the height of `$\delimsize\vert$` at first. However, the final result is not correct:

[image]

What is going wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\setsymbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {$#1\vert$}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
    \tikz[baseline=.5\l_tmpa_dim,very~thick] \draw (0,0) -- (0,\l_tmpa_dim);
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[1]\{\}{%
    \renewcommand\given{\setsymbol[\delimsize]}
    #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
    \set{a \given \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\[
    \set[\bigg]{a \given \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, as the code says... Put the baseline at the correct baseline and give the correct height (the total height is the height **plus the depth**) (not sure you already know or not, but can read chapter 11. Boxes in TeXbook or whatever-equivalent-chapter in TeX by topic)

Comment: @user202729 Thank you, I didn't know that there is a `dp`. Regarding the baseline, it seems that moving half of the line height is not enough. `baseline=.5\l_tmpa_dim-.2\baselineskip` seems to be fine but I'm not sure if `.2\baselineskip` is the correct offset.

Comment: The baseline should be put at the correct place such that the depth is equal (I don't remember if TikZ measure from top or bottom, but if you know what baseline is you can calculate the value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give the line correct height (equivalent to non-latex3 code `\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox` if `\newbox\mybox \setbox\mybox=\vbox{$#1\vert$}` is set)
2. Set the correct baseline for tikz drawing (at `baseline=\the\dp\mybox`, in non-latex3)

Bonus: Using `tikz` to draw a simple variable-width rule seems like overkill (unless fancy styles will applied to it). More efficient solutions are

- latex2e command `\rule`, as in `\rule[-\box_dp:N\l_tmpa_box]{1.2pt}{\box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box}` or
- simply primitive `\vrule`, as in `\vrule width 1.2pt height \box_ht:N\l_tmpa_box depth \box_dp:N\l_tmpa_box`. Unfortunately there seems no (public) latex3 function wrapping `\vrule` yet.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\setsymbol[1][]{%
    \nonscript\:
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {$#1\vert$}
    \tikz[baseline=\dim_eval:n {\box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box}, very~thick]
      \draw (0,0) -- (0,\dim_eval:n {\box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box});
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[1]\{\}{
    \renewcommand\given{\setsymbol[\delimsize]}
    #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
    \set{a \given \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\[
    \set[\bigg]{a \given \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a^n = 1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]